# Angular.js ng-repeat with conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to iterate over a key/value array. If the key == 'First Name' I would like to bind it to firstName. I'm new to angular.js, there may be a better way to do this? Basically I have a key/value array and some of the key's in it I would like to do something with.

```
<ul id="customers" infinite-scroll='loadMoreUsers()'>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users" data-customer-id="{{user.Id}}">

               <h4>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</h4>

            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in user.AttributeBag">
                <span ng-if="key == 'First Name'">{{user.firstName = value}}</span>
                <span ng-if="key == 'Last Name'">{{user.lastName = value}}</span></span>

                <span ng-if="key != 'First Name' && key != 'Last Name'">{{key}} : {{value}}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What's a key/value array? Object...?

Comment: A.K.A. an associative _array_

Comment: Yes, you can see in the code where I check the key and try to bind the value to firstName; with no success...

Comment: Could you please post your data structure for 'users'? Then we can help find the best way to resolve your problem with ng-repeat.:-)

Comment: I think it should be `{{user.firstName}}` and so on, but it's better if you post the `users` JSON too

Comment: Anke, Users has a associative array called AttributeBag. I iterate over it with ng-repeat. This works. I'm trying to check one of the key's to see if it is 'First Name' and bind it.

Comment: So Michelem is on the right track. I updated the code above. This works, as far as binding it. But I don't want it to show in the ng-repeat of AttributeBag, which it's doing?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-if` creates it's own child scope which is why you can't access the `key`

Two approaches I can think of

1. Use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`. `ng-show` does not create it's own scope.
2. Use `$parent` to access the parent scope. However you are using an abstraction of the `user.AttributeBag` in your `ng-repeat` so this will need some tweaking.

Comment: The above (edited) code is now working. Only problem left is it's still writing First Name and Last Name inside the ng-repeat of AttributeBag, which I don't want.

Comment: Do I understand right, that you want to bind the values, but not print them out?  If this is the case, you can hide the print out with ng -hide

Comment: Anke, ng-hide does do the trick, as far as not showing it. But it's weird, why does is even write, when all I see it doing is setting user.firstName = value.

Answer (score 1):

source : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes.
In JavaScript, arrays always use numbered indexes.
WARNING !!
If you use a named index, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object.
After that, all array methods and properties will produce incorrect results.

```
var person = [];
person["firstName"] = "John";
person["lastName"] = "Doe";
person["age"] = 46;
var x = person.length;         // person.length will return 0
var y = person[0];             // person[0] will return undefined
```

possibly what your are doing is conceptually wrong and you need to use an array of objects?

Comment: AttributeBag is an array of key / values, like 'First Name' : Steve